# Working with wildcards - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to store a list of `wild cards` within my (PostgreSQL) database.

e.g.

- `Laughing Unicorn v1.*`
- `Firefox v4.*`
- `jump * start`

where in this case `*` would mean any value.

---

After storing these values within the DB I would then like to query the db to check if a string matches any of the patterns

For example I might want to check if `Laughing Unicorn v1.8` matches any rows.

---

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Be wary of searches with wildcards anywhere but as the last character of the term.  Most such searches cannot make efficient use of indexes in this case, and will result in a dreded **full table scan**.  If you need something like that, look into a full text search, which works in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE patterns (pattern text);
INSERT INTO patterns VALUES ('Laughing Unicorn v1.*'),
                            ('Firefox v4.*'),
                            ('jump * start');
SELECT 'Laughing Unicorn v1.8' 
       LIKE ANY (SELECT replace(pattern, '*', '%') FROM patterns);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! Could you please explain why I need replace? :)

Comment: @RadianHex: Because `%` is the wildcard character for `LIKE`, not `*`.  Of course you could also write your search strings using `%` to begin with.  That depends on where you get them from.